# How to make stepped navigation using vue router?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I want to make stepped navigation for user signup page 
and i wanna make each step a different route but i need to keep url the same for each of it, so that user won't be able to go straight to step 3.

here is what i currently have 
routes:

```
{
  path: '/signup',
  component: SignupPage,
  children: [
    { path: '', name: 'signup.step1', component: SignupStep1 },
    { path: '', name: 'signup.step2', component: SignupStep2 },
    { path: '', name: 'signup.step3', component: SignupStep3 },
    { path: '', name: 'signup.step4', component: SignupStep4 }
  ]
}
```

SignupPage:

```
<header>...</header>
<router-view />
<footer>...</footer>
```

SignupStep1:

```
methods: {
  nextStep () {
    this.$router.push({ name: 'signup.step2' })
  }
  ...
}
```

but when nextStep method called nothing seems to change

Comment: _' i wanna make each step a different route but i need to keep url the same for each of it'_ - a different route but the same URL? Can you please explain better? Also, why not simply create lets say a `SignupPage.vue` components and put all logic inside it?

Comment: Don't use vue router if you don't want the url to change.

Comment: You can make navigation guards to make sure someone doesn't skip steps, just save the state somewhere. Easy to do if you are using vuex.

Comment: @artoju, no need yo use `vuex` in such a simple task. One more layer = one more problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer this question short.

Two optimal ways to solve this task - use Vuetify and its ready-to-use [Steppers-component](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/steppers) and the second one - pass data through `params` from one step to the next one.

Let me explain the second option: vue-router allows us to easily pass any type of data from one url to another without even showing that data somehow to the end user. How to pass data between urls you can read in [vue-router docs](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) and in your case you don't even need 4-5-6 components, it will be enough to use 1 component + tab bars or any other element for switching steps.

> but when nextStep method called nothing seems to change

That happens because you have 4 paths with the same value - an empty value. vue-router searches routes from top to bottom and if it finds one that matches current path no other records would be checked, thats why you see only `singup`-page.